# string representation of llvm::Type structure

Tags: c++, string, llvm, llvm-3.0

`llvm::Type` 2.9 and earlier used to have `getDescription` method to retrieve a string representation of the type. This method does not exist anymore in llvm 3.0.

I'm not sure if this is deprecated in favor of `Type::print(raw_ostream&)`, but in any case I'm curious of this API. What examples are there about how to use it? How can I dump to a `string` or `const char*`?

In particular, I want to pass the string to `Boost::Format` which is a modern c++ `sprintf`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suppose, you need to create an instance of `llvm::raw_string_ostream` and pass your std::string into it's construtor. Now you can use it as `llvm::raw_ostream` and when you are done just call `.str()` to get your string.

Something like that:

```
std::string type_str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(&type_str);
your_type->print(rso);
std::cout<<rso.str();
```

LLVM has changed its interface, so now the following will work:

```
std::string type_str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(type_str);
your_type->print(rso);
std::cout<<rso.str();
```